# DumpCount in WER doesn't work precisely

Tags: windows, crash-dumps, windows-error-reporting

I work on a Windows 64-bit PC. My application launches 10+ instances of a 32-bit process with the same name, Proc.exe. These instances are launched very close in time; in a certain scenario they crash, also very close in time.
I try to collect crash dumps for these crashes, using WER. I use the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps\Proc.exe, as explained in "Collecting User-Mode Dumps" MSDN article. I use the full dump (DumpType=2). In the target dump folder I obtain a number of dump files whose names differ by the PID number: Proc.exe.1836.dmp, Proc.exe.5428.dmp, etc.

The problem: the total number of the generated dump files is not always exactly according to the value of DumpCount, often there are more files, and their actual number varies from run to run. I saw up to 5 files for DumpCount=1, and up to 8 files for DumpCount=3.
I tried to work with the global LocalDumps settings (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps) instead of the per-process settings, and the results are similar.

It's important for me to control the number of the generated dump files, since the free disk space is very limited.

Do I miss something, or what I reported now is a bug in Windows?

Comment: That sounds like a bug to me. Maybe at the time of the crash the .dmp file hasn't actually been fully generated yet, so it hasn't yet ticked up the DumpCount. In any case, if you're working with full crash dumps (DumpType=2), disk space could very well be a problem. A very rough workaround would be to write a small program that monitors the dump folder and starts wiping out dumps after a certain threshold has been reached.

Comment: You're running a 32 bit app.  Have you tried setting the _LocalDumps_ key in the **wow6432node** of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE?